# Erro no AdapterView

Tags: android

Boa noite, estou tentando chamar uma activty por um Adapter por meio de intent, mas dá o seguinte erro:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                                  Process: com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.navigationdrawervideotutorial, PID: 20374
>                                                                                                                  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.navigationdrawervideotutorial/br.com.projeto.caminhossembarreiras.activity.Activity_Acess}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>                                                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1885)
>                                                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1697)
>                                                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4557)
>                                                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:4543)
>                                                                                                                      at android.app.Activity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:6623)
>                                                                                                                      at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1092)
>                                                                                                                      at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1071)
>                                                                                                                      at br.com.projeto.caminhossembarreiras.AcessFragment.onItemClick(AcessFragment.java:39)
>                                                                                                                      at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
>                                                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
>                                                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3049)
>                                                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3886)
>                                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Fragment do Adapter:

```
public class AcessFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private ListView lista;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_acess, container, false);

    lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista);
    lista.setAdapter(new AdapterAcess(getContext()));
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int idx , long id) {

    if (idx == 0) {
        Intent it = new Intent(getContext(), Activity_Acess.class);
        startActivity(it);
    } else if (idx == 1) {

    } else if (idx == 2) {

    } else if (idx == 3) {

    } else if (idx == 4) {

    }

}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#ececec"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:dividerHeight="2sp"
    />
```

Adapter:

```
public class AdapterAcess extends BaseAdapter {

private String[] itens = new String[]{"Acessibilidade", "Seus Direitos", "Outros"};
private Context context;

public AdapterAcess(Context context){
    super();
    this.context = context; // O context é necessario para criar a view.
}

@Override

public int getCount() {
    return itens.length; // Retorna a quantida de itens do adapter.
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return itens[position]; // Retorna o objeto para esta posição.
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position; // Retorna o id do obejto para esta posição;
}

@Override
// Retorna o view para esta posição.
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    String lista = itens[position];
    TextView t = new TextView(context);
    float dip = 50;
    float densidade = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; // Densidade da tela.

    int px = (int) (dip * densidade + 0.5f);
    t.setHeight(px);
    t.setText(lista);
    return t;

}
```

}

Comment: bem aqui: "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?", você provavelmente não declarou sua activity no manifest file, todas as activities que voce venha a usar devem ser declaradas lá, se quiser saber como fazer isso: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html, se voce pesquisar no google vai char alguns tutoriais mais diretos e simples

Comment: Obrigdo, bom saber isso. To começando agora em android!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qualquer activity que você for chamar, seja através de: intent, botões, side scroll etc, deve ser declarada no manifest. Criei um novo projeto para melhor exemplificar.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ajuda.ajuda.ajuda">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
        android:name=".NEW_ACTIVITY"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Repare que dentro da TAG application, adicionei uma nova activity chamada: **NEW_ACTIVITY** se ela não for declarada aqui, quando chama-la através de outra activity, o app vai "crashar".

Qualquer duvida, olhe este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zGoM5VIQh8 me ajudou bastante quando comecei, e ainda está em português.

Comment: Obrigado, tenho certeza que vai me ajudar bastante!